# Не срабатывает getXML

Tags: xml, jquery

```
var fData = getXML(xmlData);
//в xmlData лежит значение (проверила с помощью alert), например: 
//<root><status>1</status><operation_type>insert</operation_type><res>226</res></root> 
jQuery(fData).find("root").each(function () { //не выполняется тело
    var vStatus = jQuery(this).find("status").text();
    if (vStatus == "-1") {
        jQuery("#info_msg").html("Внимание! Произошла ошибка! Повторите операцию либо обратитесь к разработчикам!");
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: `poeration_type>insert</operation_type ? poeration vs operation` - а вот тут поди разберись то ли это пришел неправельный ответ с серверной части то-ли вы криво текст вбили

Comment: это я криво вбила. там все норм

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery при обработке xml-кода сразу начинает отсчет от `<root>`, поэтому выполняйте код без `find("root")`:

```
var fData = getXML(xmlData);
var vStatus = jQuery(fData).find("status").text();
if (vStatus == "-1") {
    jQuery("#info_msg").html("Внимание! Произошла ошибка! Повторите операцию либо обратитесь к разработчикам!");
}
```

Comment: убрала, все равно не работает

Comment: У меня работает:

    var vStatus = jQuery('<root><status>1</status><operation_type>insert</operation_type><res>226</res></root>').find("status").text();
    alert(vStatus);

Если у вас не работает, значит, в `fData` ерунда, либо поправьте xml.

Comment: после fData = getXML(xmlData); если alert-ом вывести эту переменную, получается что он undefinde. Что не так с ним? Сам xml нормальный

Comment: убрала getXML и работала с XMLdataю все пашет. спасибо